# VB.NET: How to convert string to Date?

Tags: vb.net, date

I have string coming in through an SSIS package via text file in form:

```
"20090910" (string)
```

and it needs to be

```
2010-09-01 00:00:00 (Date)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

Example from MSDN with your data:

```
Dim dateString, format As String  
Dim result As Date
Dim provider As Globalization.CultureInfo = Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

' Parse date and time with custom specifier.
dateString = "20090910"
format = "yyyyMMdd"        
Try
   result = Date.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider)
   Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, result.ToString())
   Console.ReadLine()
Catch e As FormatException
   Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString)
End Try
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to like this. ssis gives really obscure errors and i can't step through code in a script component

Comment: it says : Conversion from string "2"" to type 'Double' is not valid.

Comment: i imported system.globalization

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the full error that SSIS gives you? Stack trace and all.  **Most important is the line number that the error reports, and then statement on the corresponding line number**. It appears that the error isn't related to the datetime parsing, but it's not clear.

Comment: Ugh, it seems that I fixed the problem, there were quotations coming in around the string "2009.." so i did a string.replace to take them out and it works now.  sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: You may wish to use TryParseExact to avoid any exception if the string doesn't come in with your expected format.